# Move folder directory to secondary drive

Tags: hard-drive, home-directory

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 onto my PC.  The OS is on my SSD and that is the only thing I want on it.  I have a previously-formatted 1TB hard drive in my computer which has several folders and files that I moved over from my original 500GB hard drive.  Before installing Ubuntu, my computer ran Windows and only had the 500GB hard drive in it.

Basic information:
I want to use the 1TB hard drive as storage.  I don't know how to change the directory or path or whatever.  More details below.

The most important thing being:
I want all Home subfolders to be redirected to my 1TB hard drive, possibly while maintaining the Ubuntu default appearance.  I hope to store program files onto the hard drive, but I think programs won't run from a secondary drive.

Less important:
I want to change folders around in the Computer folder (my SSD).  Currently, my secondary drive has the following path from the Computer folder:  /media/*username*/Hard Drive.  Hard Drive is the only folder under *username*, and *username* is the only folder under media.  I want the Hard Drive folder to be directly under the Computer folder.  The Home folder can stay in the Computer folder.  I feel that I want all the OS folders in an OS folder.  That would leave three subfolders under the Computer folder.  It would be great if those three folders could be permanently larger; an appearance like "My Computer" in Windows.  Also having the Hard Drive folder showing available GB space underneath the folder icon.

**I found the following information but I don't know if I will lose data from my hard drive by doing what it says:**
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: The link looks good. The procedure is designed to be failsafe but if you feel uncomfortable you can always backup your home folder to the 500Gb drive first, this way you know you can always recover. The guide explains how to mount a disk/partition in a different place using fstab which should help with your second question.

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand *fstab*.  The 500GB drive is not in the PC.  And what is my second question?

Comment: Your _less important_ one: You might want to add an fstab entry for your drive so it doesn't show up under /media anymore. If you're not familiar with fstab you might want to read [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38125/htg-explains-what-is-the-linux-fstab-and-how-does-it-work/) and `man fstab`. If you still don't understand afterwards you should probably leave it where it is =)

Comment: There is a script issue with that link.  I felt like my computer was being hacked.

Comment: The procedure from the link seems not to work properly for me.  I think it is because the partition on the secondary drive is NTFS.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  
The directions in the link seem to work.  I was worried about losing data from my 1TB HDD.  So, I repartitioned the 500GB drive (existing data on this drive, I didn't care about), then moved my data from the 1TB to the 500GB.  After moving over the data, I repartitioned the 1TB drive because NTFS format is not compatible with Linux in this situation.  
"When you do create a new partition it is highly suggested that you create an ext3 or ext4 partition to house your new home directory."  -from link